# Return a recordset from a SQL CLR Assembly?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, assemblies, clr, sqlclr

Guys lease help me out I think I'm close, but I'm missing something.

### **Background**

I'm rewriting a SQL CLR assembly (stored procedure), my assembly contacts another resource and gets back XML. I want to return this XML as a recordset, NOT a scalar value.

From what I've seen, this is how to return a recordset:

```
SqlContext.Pipe.Send(mySqlDataReader)
```

The **Send** method takes in 3 possible parameters:

```
public void Send(string message);
public void Send(SqlDataRecord record);
public void Send(SqlDataReader reader);
```

The **SqlDataReader** class does not have a constructor, how does SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()  return one?

### **What I think I need to do**

- Create my own class inheriting from
  **IDataReader**.
- Make this class consume the XML, and expose it as
  records (like a DataReader).
- **Override SqlDataReader and pass this to SqlContext.Pipe.Send(mySqlDataReader)
  ???**

This is where it gets fuzzy.

### **How do I return my custom recordset back to SQL Server?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you'd better use SqlDataRecord. You can see a description [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.server.sqldatarecord.aspx)

It should look like follows:

```
 SqlDataRecord record = new SqlDataRecord(new SqlMetaData[] { new SqlMetaData("Column1", SqlDbType.NVarChar)});

 // Set the record fields.
 record.SetString(0, youVariableWithXmlData);

 // Send the data
 SqlContext.Pipe.Send(record);
```

Answer (score 0):

First: Assemblies do not return anything, they simply contain one or more methods that might return result sets, scalar values, return values.

If you already have a `SqlDataReader` (it is unclear from the wording of the Question), then you were very close with having the result set returned.

> The SqlDataReader class does not have a constructor, how does SqlCommand.ExecuteReader() return one?

How the `ExecuteReader` method creates the `SqlDataReader` isn't important. What *is* important is that it *does* return a `SqlDataReader`. Hence, you just need to do the following:

```cs
SqlDataReader _Reader = SqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
SqlContext.Pipe.Send(_Reader);
// be sure to call .Dispose() on the SqlDataReader, SqlCommand, and SqlConnection objects,
// if they are not each in their own using() blocks
```

That method is pretty efficient, but doesn't allow you to intercept the rows of the SqlDataReader before passing them back as result set rows. So if you need to manipulate the values before sending them back to the caller, use the following methods of `SqlContext.Pipe`:

- `SendResultsStart(SqlDataRecord)`
- `SendResultsRow(SqlDataRecord)`
- `SendResultsEnd()`